# Prevent script from closing by sys.exit()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to call 1 script(test.py) every 5 minutes, so i have used another script timer.py with following code:

```
import time
while(1==1):
    execfile("test.py")
    time.sleep(300)
```

This works correctly.
But it stopped working after few iterations. After debugging i found that there is a flow in test.py which uses following code:

```
sys.exit()
```

So, this is causing both test.py and timer.py to stop.
what changes should be done, so as to continue timer.py since i want sys.exit() to only exit test.py and not timer.py

Comment: Can you show the code of `test.py`? Also you can change `while(1==1)` to `while True`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`sys.exit()` doesn't do more then raising `SystemExit` (a `BaseException` subclass), which can be caught like any exception e.g:

```
import time
while True:
    try:
        execfile("test.py")
    except SystemExit:
        print("ignoring SystemExit")
    finally:
        time.sleep(300)
```

Comment: Thanks, i have implemented this.

Answer (score 1):

Use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

```py
import subprocess  
import time

while(1==1):
    subprocess.call(['python', './test.py'])
    time.sleep(300)
```

You could even remove the *python* word if the `test.py` file has a shebang comment on the first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

This is not exactly the same, as it will start a new interpreter, but the results will be similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import time
import os
while True:
    os.system("python test.py") # if you are not running script from same directory then mention complete path to the file
    time.sleep(300)
```

Comment: Works, but open a command window on every execution, which is disturbance to me. Earlier, everything used to be in background.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

```
try:
  # Your call here
except BaseException as ex:
  print("This should be a possible sys.exit()")
```

Check out [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit) for more information.